# period of polar curves curves

Tags: polar-coordinates

Given a polar curve in the form $r=a+b\cos(k \theta)$,how can I find the length of the interval for which the curve has its complete form? (I'm looking for the period of such curves)

I'm asking this question,since I think it's necessary for plotting the graph of such polar curves.

Answer (score 1):

$ k \theta\;$ varies between $0- 2 \pi$

If $k=3,\;$ then the period is $\dfrac {2 \pi}{3}$

If $k=\dfrac12,\; $ then the period is ${4 \pi}.$

Polar plot for $ k= 3$ has period $\theta =!20^{\circ}$. This is the period; in other words angular difference between consecutive maximum radii or minimum radii.

[image]

Comment: How do you prove the formula you've used for computing the period?

Comment: It is in the formative definition of circular trigonometric functions. One rotation around a point is $2 \pi$ or $360^{\circ}$ and.. that is *defined* as its period.

Comment: It known that period of a function $f(x)=cos(bx)$ is equal to $\frac{2\pi}{\left|b\right|}$.

How to prove that?

Comment: If three people have a pie, how much does each one get? If $b$ number of waves are huddled and squeezed into one period how narrow can each wave get? Respect your own intuition. Proof does not come from any high-up store always. Hope it is not hard... .if you feel so, forgive.